# Sim does not go to work although car is waiting

Tags: the-sims-3

After my sim moved, he does not go to work anymore. When the car waits in front of the house, he simply does not get it. Even if I click on the car and choose "go to work", nothing happens.

Is this a known bug? How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to zoom out into the Town View, locate the building in which your sim works, select it and choose 'Go to Work' - I have never encountered your specific glitch though, so can only say that this is one of the other ways of sending a sim to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resolve this bug permanently, but there is a workaround: Click on your sim and let him change to the "Carrier" outfit. After that, clicking on the car and choosing "go to work" works.

Unfortunately, you have to do this every time the sim has to go to work.